# medias columnas y filas css htmltd

Tags: html, css

No puedo dar medidas a los th td
en el css

```
th{ width:300;
    background-color:orange;
    }

.codigo {
width:200px;
}


<tr>
    <th class="codigo">Codigo unico</th>
    <th>IP del equipo</th>
    <th>Tipo del equipo</th>
    <th>Nombre del equipo</th>
    <th>Area asignada</th>
    <th>Anexo telefonico</th>
    <th>Sistema Operativo</th>
    <th>Disco Duro</th>
    <th>Procesador</th>
    <th>Ram</th>
    <th>Direccion Fisica</th>
    <th>Offimatica</th>
    <th>Correo</th>
    <th>Punto de Acceso</th>
    <th>Tipo de pantalla</th>
    <th>Modelo</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

En HTML 5 funciona bien trabajar con el `min-width`, esto te permite de tener una medida minima. para mas informacion [visita esta](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) pagina en ingles

```css
th{
   min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>

<tr>
    <th class="codigo">Codigo unico</th>
    <th>IP del equipo</th>
    <th>Tipo del equipo</th>
    <th>Nombre del equipo</th>
    <th>Area asignada</th>
    <th>Anexo telefonico</th>
    <th>Sistema Operativo</th>
    <th>Disco Duro</th>
    <th>Procesador</th>
    <th>Ram</th>
    <th>Direccion Fisica</th>
    <th>Offimatica</th>
    <th>Correo</th>
    <th>Punto de Acceso</th>
    <th>Tipo de pantalla</th>
    <th>Modelo</th>
</tr>

</table>
```